# Django: Get remote IP address inside settings.py

Tags: python, django

I want to enable debug (`DEBUG = True`) For my Django project only if it runs on localhost. How can I get user IP address inside settings.py? I would like something like this to work:

```
#Debugging only on localhost
if user_ip = '127.0.0.1':
    DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = False
```

How do I put user IP address in `user_ip` variable inside `settings.py` file?

Comment: zefciu's answers seems to fit the bill; one note though - to me it seems that in your question you are mixing client ip and ip that django is bound to.

Comment: I mean client IP. The one we usually get using request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it is enough for you to specify some INTERNAL_IPS:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#internal-ips

Answer (score 3):

use this.

```
import socket

print socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]
```

*edit: ah, i had misunderstood the topic.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you settings.py

```
class LazyDebugSetting(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def __nonzero__(self):
        if not self.value:
           # as emre yilmaz say
           user_ip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]
           self.value = user_ip == '127.0.0.1'
        return self.value 
    __len__ = __nonzero__

DEBUG = LazyDebugSetting()
```

But better use the INTERNAL_IPS

Or use environment variables

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEVELOP_MODE', False)
```